# error in split() Error in 1:dim(X)[along] : NA/NaN argument

Tags: r

I am trying to use the split() function from baseR to split this data frame into multiple data frames based on the HUC4 column. I keep encountering an error that prevents the function from working. I have not found a solution online.

```
   Saris/Palis       SznYr HUC4
1        1100500 2003-Winter  202
2        1100500   2017-Fall  202
3        1100500 2017-Summer  202
4        1100525 2006-Winter  202
5        1100525 2016-Winter  202
1200     5131700 2012-Summer  109
1201     5131700   2015-Fall  109
1202     5131700 2015-Spring  109
1203     5131700 2016-Winter  109
1204     5131775 2007-Spring  109
1205     5131780 2006-Winter  109
800      3522425 2007-Spring  108
801      3522450 2006-Spring  108
802      3522450   2007-Fall  108
803      3522450 2007-Summer  108
804      3522450 2011-Summer  108
805      3522450 2012-Spring  108

split(df,df$HUC4)

Error in 1:dim(X)[along] : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (along < 0) along = length(dim(X)) - along + 1 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In 1:dim(X)[along] :
  numerical expression has 17 elements: only the first used
```

Comment: `split` is a `base R` function.  By using the code and the data, not able to reproduce the error

Comment: good catch, thanks! fixed in post.

Comment: What is your intended output?

Comment: Can you check the `str(df)` to check if these are all normal columns and not some nested lists

Answer (score 1):

The following code actually works:

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = " Saris/Palis       SznYr HUC4
1        1100500 2003-Winter  202
2        1100500   2017-Fall  202
3        1100500 2017-Summer  202
4        1100525 2006-Winter  202
5        1100525 2016-Winter  202
1200     5131700 2012-Summer  109
1201     5131700   2015-Fall  109
1202     5131700 2015-Spring  109
1203     5131700 2016-Winter  109
1204     5131775 2007-Spring  109
1205     5131780 2006-Winter  109
800      3522425 2007-Spring  108
801      3522450 2006-Spring  108
802      3522450   2007-Fall  108
803      3522450 2007-Summer  108
804      3522450 2011-Summer  108
805      3522450 2012-Spring  108")

split(df, df$HUC4)

# $`108`
# Saris.Palis       SznYr HUC4
# 800     3522425 2007-Spring  108
# 801     3522450 2006-Spring  108
# 802     3522450   2007-Fall  108
# 803     3522450 2007-Summer  108
# 804     3522450 2011-Summer  108
# 805     3522450 2012-Spring  108
# 
# $`109`
# Saris.Palis       SznYr HUC4
# 1200     5131700 2012-Summer  109
# 1201     5131700   2015-Fall  109
# 1202     5131700 2015-Spring  109
# 1203     5131700 2016-Winter  109
# 1204     5131775 2007-Spring  109
# 1205     5131780 2006-Winter  109
# 
# $`202`
# Saris.Palis       SznYr HUC4
# 1     1100500 2003-Winter  202
# 2     1100500   2017-Fall  202
# 3     1100500 2017-Summer  202
# 4     1100525 2006-Winter  202
# 5     1100525 2016-Winter  202
```

So my guess would be that the data frame in your usage has structural issues.

Can you post `str(df)` ?

Comment: str(reprex_data)
'data.frame': 17 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Saris/Palis: num  1100500 1100500 1100500 1100525 1100525 ...
 $ SznYr      : Factor w/ 76 levels "1998-Fall","1998-Summer",..: 21 73 75 32 72 55 65 66 72 34 ...
 $ HUC4       : chr  "202" "202" "202" "202" ...